# WordPress multisite with multiple parent domains

Tags: multisite, domain, domain-mapping

I know that I can map multiple domains to individual blogs through plugins. 
But is it possible to configure WordPress multisite to have more than one parent domain?

Ie., a user wants to create a blog. We use the standard form for that, but apart from choosing their own subdomain, I'd like to be able to give them a choice of parent domains as well. Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  You want to present them with a list of possible domains to choose from, to map to their network (subdomain or subdirectory) site within your multisite installation?

Comment: Both, actually. 
One could sign up for the network and get a "basic" site. When that happens I'd like to be able to offer a selection of domains for their site to have their subdomain with, ie. example.com and test.com? 
But I'd also like to retain the possibility of mapping their own demo.com to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Like C C said some clarification would be helpful. If it helps, you can actually still use a subdomain and point the primary domain to it (the subdomain) using a flattened CNAME record. It is RFC compliant and functions the exact same as pointing the primary domain to an IP using an A record. Maybe this mitigates your problem. This article by CloudFlare explains it further: [CNAME Flattening by CloudFlare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/)

This is a free service by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be interested in a WordPress Multi Network.  See if this meets your needs: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/